# How do I take log from terminal and console.log it in the browser? nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get data from an api, and when i run node app.js in my terminal I get the data from the api.

I want to take this data and console.log() it in order to display it on the browser. How can i achieve this?

Here is what the terminal returns:

```
PS C:\Users\Gili\Downloads\TransfermarktAPI> node app.js
```

{"url":"/lionel-messi/profil/spieler/28003","id":"28003","name":"Messi","nameInHomeCountry":"Lionel Andrés Messi Cuccitini","imageURL":"https://img.a.transfermarkt.technology/portrait/header/28003-1690045464.jpg?lm=1","dateOfBirth":"Jun 24, 1987","placeOfBirth":{"city":"Rosario","country":"Argentina"},"age":"36","height":"1,70m","citizenship":["Argentina","Spain"],"isRetired":false,"position":{"main":"Right Winger","other":["Centre-Forward","Second Striker"]},"foot":"left","shirtNumber":"#10","club":{"id":"69261","name":"Miami","joined":"Jul 15, 2023","contractExpires":"Dec 31, 2025"},"marketValue":{"current":"€35.00m","highest":"€180.00m"},"outfitter":"adidas","socialMedia":["http://www.facebook.com/LeoMessi","http://instagram.com/leomessi","http://www.leomessi.com"],"lastUpdate":"2023-08-30T16:37:18.495580"}
PS C:\Users\Gili\Downloads\TransfermarktAPI>

Here is my code:

```
import request from 'request';

const url = 'https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/28003/profile';
const headers = {
 'accept': 'application/json'
};

request({
    url,
    headers
},

  (err, response, body) => {
   if (err) {

    console.error(err);

   } else {

    console.log(body);
   }
});
```

thank you

Comment: Which browser are u talking about? You are running you JavaScript with NodeJS, a JavaScript runtime environment which does not use any browser to execute the JavaScript Code.

Comment: If you want to use your JS code within the context of a browser, create a simple HTML website and embedded your code within `<script></script>` tags. But It won't work as the package "request" is not available. The WebAPIs that browsers provides differs from NodeJS. Both has been build for different puposes. Instead you need to use the [featch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: I tried using the fetch api but i got some "cors" issues which turned way to complex than they should have. so i borrowed this code which i works in node js but not when i simply console.log() it. so i was wondering if there is a way to grab that and display it on the browser because i kept getting errors there.

Answer (score -1):

Node.js is server side runtime implementation of JS. It doesn't have access to the browser console api. If you add console.log in node, it will only print in the terminal where you are running the node process. If you are calling your node endpoint and the node endpoint is calling another api, you need to send the response of the api call you are making in node to the browser and then you can print that response in the console. Though there are some chrome extensions, that allow you to debug node code in the browser.